# Game object doesn't render in camera

Tags: rendering, game-engine, camera

I'm creating little game with a third-person-camera.
Everything was rendering fine, until suddenly, after moving some background objects... my main character **stopped rendering inside the camera view**... without having changed anything to it or its material.
Outside the camera view it's rendering just fine.

The weird thing is that the **shadow still renders** fine inside camera view.

Please help! Thanks!

Inside Camera view (unrendered)
[image: Inside camera (unrendered)]

inside Camera (rendered P)
[image]

Comment: Either something about your game logic, animation or rigging is causing that, but we can't really know because you don't provide enough information to diagnose. Please edit your question and give us more details possibly upload a **simplified** [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) with packed textures with the minimum possible data to recreate the problem

Comment: I accidentally fixed it. The size of my camera was too large for some reason. Once I scaled it down, the object showed up again in camera view.

Next time I have a question, I'll keep in mind to provide a simplified blend file.
Thanks!